# Pgcrypto commands produce non-standard output

Tags: postgresql, output, pgcrypto

Each time i run 'encrypt' or 'digest' commands my output contains multiple instances of character '\'.

See example "select encrypt('123456789012345','1234','aes');" - expected output: 
"\x34591627f9c8eae417fc7cbbf458592c"

whereas my output is as follows:
"4Y\026'\371\310\352\344\027\374|\273\364XY,"

The same applies to digest commands; have i installed pgcrypto incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [return type of `encrypt`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgcrypto.html#AEN185551) is `bytea`, which can be represented in [different ways](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html). Your two different outputs are merely two representations of the *same value* (mind the weird escaping in the “escape” format):

```
test=# select (bytea E'4Y\\026''\\371\\310\\352\\344\\027\\374|\\273\\364XY,') =
test-#        (bytea '\x34591627f9c8eae417fc7cbbf458592c') as eq;
 eq 
----
 t
(1 row)
```

On my installation of PostgreSQL, "hex" format is the default one, but since that's not true for you, you can set `bytea_output`, which controls the output of byte values:

```
test=# select encrypt('123456789012345','1234','aes');
                   encrypt                   
---------------------------------------------
 4Y\026'\371\310\352\344\027\374|\273\364XY,
(1 row)

test=# set bytea_output = 'hex';
SET
test=# select encrypt('123456789012345','1234','aes');
              encrypt               
------------------------------------
 \x34591627f9c8eae417fc7cbbf458592c
(1 row)
```

You can also explicitly encode the bytes to get a `text` value:

```
test=# select encode(encrypt('123456789012345','1234','aes'), 'hex');
              encode              
----------------------------------
 34591627f9c8eae417fc7cbbf458592c
(1 row)
```